# Grub can't find RAID partition in fresh install of 11.04

Tags: 11.04, grub2, dell, raid

I attempted to install 11.04 on a Dell PowerEdge-R610 that has a LSI SAS1068E-based hardware RAID setup (I think).  Installer finishes without a hitch, but upon reboot, it appears that Grub can't find the boot partition and drops to the busybox shell.

Here is the partition table on the RAID device.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 72.7 GB, 72746008576 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8844 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d08d6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        6757    54272000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            6757        8845    16765953    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            6757        8845    16765952   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

And here is the Grub script as produced by the installer.  The msdos stuff looks fishy to me.  (Please note, this was typed by hand and may contain typos.)

```
setparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic'

recordfail
set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 22f9995f-8060-4893-9b9a-bed1d2635384
linux /boot/vmlinux-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=22f9995f-8060-4893-9b9a-bed1d2635384 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
```

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After baning my head against this server for a few days, it turns out the magical incantation was simply to add "rootdelay=90" to the kernel command in the Grub menu.  It simply wasn't waiting long enough for the RAID controller to initialize.